# Почему не работает движение персонажа с помощью кнопок?

Tags: unity3d

Что в моем коде реализовано не правильно? Сломал себе уже всю голову. Кнопки все назначил, но при нажатии кнопки влево или вправо игрок просто стоит на месте.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float speedForse = 7f;
[SerializeField] private float speed = 0f;
[SerializeField] private float jumpForse = 7f;
[SerializeField] private float wallJumpColdown;

[SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask wallLayer;

[HideInInspector] public bool isFacingRight = true;

public bool RightButton = false;
public bool LeftButton = false;
public bool JumpButton = false;

private enum MovementState { idle, running, jumping, falling, walljumping, shoot }

private float dirX;

private Rigidbody2D body;
private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
private Animator anim;

private PlayerShoot ps;

private void Start()
{
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    ps = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerShoot>();
}

private void Update()
{
    //dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    //Проверка просмотра в какую сторону смотрит игрок для разварота текстуры
    if (RightButton == true)
    {
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        print(body.velocity);
        body.velocity = new Vector2(speedForse, body.velocity.y);
        print(body.velocity);
        isFacingRight = true;
    }
    else if (LeftButton == true)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        print(body.velocity);
        body.velocity = new Vector2(- speedForse, body.velocity.y);
        print(body.velocity);
        isFacingRight = false;
    }

    //Прыжок от стены
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || JumpButton == true)
    {
        jump();
    }
    if (wallJumpColdown > 0.2f)
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * speedForse, body.velocity.y); 

        if (onWall() && !isGrounded())
        {
            body.gravityScale = 0;
            body.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
        else
            body.gravityScale = 1;
      
    }
    else
        wallJumpColdown += Time.deltaTime;
    UpdateAnimatState();
}

public void OnRightButton()
{
    RightButton = true;
    speed = speedForse;
}

public void OnLeftButton()
{
    LeftButton = true;
    speed = -speedForse;
}

public void OnJumpButton()
{
    JumpButton = true;
}

private void jump()
{
    if (isGrounded())
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, jumpForse); 
    }
    else if (onWall() && !isGrounded())
    {
        if (dirX == 0)
        {
                body.velocity = new Vector2(-Mathf.Sign(transform.localScale.x) * 10, 0);
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(-Mathf.Sign(transform.localScale.x),
                    transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
        }
        else
        {
                body.velocity = new Vector2(-Mathf.Sign(transform.localScale.x) * 3, 6);
                wallJumpColdown = 0;
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateAnimatState()
{
    MovementState state;

    if (dirX > 0f)
    {
        state = MovementState.running;
    }
    else
    {
        state = MovementState.idle;
    }

    if (body.velocity.y > 0.1f)
    {
        state = MovementState.jumping;
    }
    else if (body.velocity.y < -0.1f)
    {
        state = MovementState.falling;
    }

    if (body.gravityScale == 0f)
    {
        state = MovementState.walljumping;
    }

    if (ps.isShoot == true)
    {
        state = MovementState.shoot;
    }

    anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
}

private bool isGrounded()
{
    RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider.bounds.center, 
        boxCollider.bounds.size, 0, Vector2.down, 0.1f, groundLayer);
    return raycastHit.collider != null;
}

private bool isRoof()
{
    {
        RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider.bounds.center,
            boxCollider.bounds.size, 0, Vector2.up, 0.1f, groundLayer);
        return raycastHit.collider != null;
    }
}

private bool onWall()
{
    RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider.bounds.center,
        boxCollider.bounds.size, 0, new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, 0), 0.01f, wallLayer);
    return raycastHit.collider != null;
}

public bool canAttack()
{
    return dirX == 0 && isGrounded() && !onWall();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу в этом скрипте где вы принимаете инпуты кнопок влево/вправо. Разве что строка

```
//dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
```

Но она закомменчена. Из за этого, по идее, не должно даже скомпилироваться.
Так же, раз вы берете **GetAxisRaw()** проверьте в настройках проекта на какие кнопки назначен ввод с клавиатуры. Может стоит попробовать использовать **GetAxis()**?

Comment: У меня UI кнопки для движения и я двигаю игрока на заданную константу. В любом случае я уже разобрался проблема была в том, что в годе дальше я обнулял положение игрока. (body.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * speedForse, body.velocity.y);) вот этой строчкой, когда ее убрал все стало работать